# Deletion in a Binary SubTree

Tags: binary-search-tree

I am trying to delete a node that has a left and a right child in this case D.

```
                 D
                /  \ 
               A    F 
                \
                 B
```

So when I try to Delete D , I should be replacing it with B , because B is the next biggest element in left sub tree. So instead of replacing it with B can I replace it with F ?

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it will not be optimal. You want your tree always to be as balanced as possible, so that insertion and deletion will stick around O(log n)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just a binary tree is unsorted. I assume your tree is a binary search tree. If all you want is keep the tree sorted than yes, you can replace it with F for this specific example. If your tree is more complex, you won't be able to do this without additional actions - e.g., you'll need to do something with children of F if present and it will require additional unnecessary processing.